# Using Testing framework how do we add test description in the (reportng) xml report

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng, jira-zephyr

This is my Test case

```
@Test(enabled=true, description="Test zip coding")
public void testZIPGeocodingAUValid() {
```

}

This is the xml report below.
How do we add the description in the xml report ?

[image]

```
<testsuite name="RegressionTest" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" time="1.365">
    <testcase name="testZIPGeocodingAUValid" time="1.365" classname="com.api.suite.APIZIPGeocoding"/>
</testsuite>

<testsuite name="RegressionTest" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" time="1.365"></testsuite>
```

Comment: It should show in your TestNG report when you run the XML file.

Comment: no, it doesnt show the test description

Comment: Add a screenshot of your report?

Comment: I have attached the report picture

Comment: When you right click it and you run it, this is what your result ends up looking like?

Comment: right,  I want to see the test description in there. I dont know how to add that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160564/discussion-between-user2511126-and-reezo).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160657/discussion-between-user2511126-and-reezo).